# UDP listener under Kestrel

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp, kestrel

I have a working C# solution, running a custom TCP server for a proprietary protocol under Kestrel .NET5:

The complete HostBuilder is

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) => config.AddTileCaseConvertedEnvironmentVariables())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) => config.AddEnvironmentVariables())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) => config.AddJsonFile("settings.json", true))
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) => config.AddJsonFile("Version.json"))
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddNLog();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o => o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
                {
                    o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                    o.ClientCertificateValidation = (_, chain, policyErrors) =>
                    {
                        if (policyErrors != System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        var cryptoManager = s_host.Services.GetRequiredService<ICryptoManager>();
                        if (cryptoManager.ClientCertificateValidationDisabled)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements)
                        {
                            if (cryptoManager.HasPinnedCA(element.Certificate))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    };
                }
                ));
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = s_maxConcurrentConnections;


                    options.ListenAnyIP(s_p2pFrontendPort, o =>
                    {
                        o.UseConnectionHandler<TCPConnectionHandler<ApduMessage, WpduMessage>>();
                        //o.UseConnectionLogging();
                    });
                });
            });
}
```

But the relevant part is only

```
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = s_maxConcurrentConnections;


                options.ListenAnyIP(s_p2pFrontendPort, o =>
                {
                    o.UseConnectionHandler<TCPConnectionHandler<ApduMessage, WpduMessage>>();
                    //o.UseConnectionLogging();
                });
            });
```

where a `ConnectionHandler` is plugged-in. My class`TCPConnectionHandler` is very simple: Whenever a connection has been accepted Kestrel `OnConnectedAsync` is called, which passes the context to some other component, dealing with reading/processing/writing/.

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(ConnectionContext connection)
{
    await _frontendListener.OnConnected(connection).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Now, the Question:

how can I use this mechanism to listen (on other port) *additionally* over UDP instead of TCP?
I find no way to tell Kestrel not to use TCP. Is it possible at all? I couldn't figure out how it could work. Or should I run the UDP service separately and forget Kestrel?

Thanks ;-)

EDIT:

In the meantime I'm more aware about UDP is datagram-oriented and connectionless, therefore, in my opinion, always a whole datagram is received instead of reading from a stream, as is the situation for TCP sockets. Now I guess it makes no sense to think about using Kestrel for that purpose. Right?

Comment: Best thing you can probably do is mix in your own `HostedService` manually listening to UDP data, matching it to your TCP clients via endpoint address and user identifier, and then dispatching the received data to some common handler, I suppose. AFAIK Project Bedrock wanted to add such functionality to Kestrel (IIRC) but it's currently not being actively worked on.